# How to avoid excessive boilerplate for matching constructors

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am currently implementing a Lexer / Parser. And one thing that bugs me is that currently half of my code in my Parser.hs is going to be dedicated to simply getting a single token:

For a small data type like this:

```
data Tok
    = IdLower String 
    | IdUpper String 
    | IdSymbol String
    | IdColon String
    | Equals
    | Newline
```

I seem to need something like this:

```
idLower :: Parser String
idLower = get >>= \s -> if
    | (_, IdLower n) :- xs <- s -> put xs *> pure n
    | (l, t) :- _ <- s -> throwError [(l, "Unexpected " <> description t)]
    | Nil l <- s -> throwError [(l, "Unexpected end of input")]

idUpper :: Parser String
idUpper = get >>= \s -> if
    | (_, IdUpper n) :- xs <- s -> put xs *> pure n
    | (l, t) :- _ <- s -> throwError [(l, "Unexpected " <> description t)]
    | Nil l <- s -> throwError [(l, "Unexpected end of input")]

idSymbol :: Parser String
idSymbol = get >>= \s -> if
    | (_, IdSymbol n) :- xs <- s -> put xs *> pure n
    | (l, t) :- _ <- s -> throwError [(l, "Unexpected " <> description t)]
    | Nil l <- s -> throwError [(l, "Unexpected end of input")]

idColon :: Parser String
idColon = get >>= \s -> if
    | (_, IdColon n) :- xs <- s -> put xs *> pure n
    | (l, t) :- _ <- s -> throwError [(l, "Unexpected " <> description t)]
    | Nil l <- s -> throwError [(l, "Unexpected end of input")]

equals :: Parser ()
equals = get >>= \s -> if
    | (_, Equals) :- xs <- s -> put xs
    | (l, t) :- _ <- s -> throwError [(l, "Unexpected " <> description t)]
    | Nil l <- s -> throwError [(l, "Unexpected end of input")]

newline :: Parser ()
newline = get >>= \s -> if
    | (_, Newline) :- xs <- s -> put xs
    | (l, t) :- _ <- s -> throwError [(l, "Unexpected " <> description t)]
    | Nil l <- s -> throwError [(l, "Unexpected end of input")]
```

Which is like 99% repeated code, the only difference between them is the constructor used, and whether or not I have something like `pure n` for the ones that have contents.

I have tried refactoring it a bit so that I have just one `Tok -> Maybe ()` or `Tok -> Maybe String` function per symbol, and then made a higher order function that takes these functions as parameters. But each `Tok -> Maybe a` function takes at 3 lines plus 1 line of spacer, and now I need another higher order function to support it, and if I want shorthands so I can just use `idLower` instead of `getToken idLower` then I end up with just as much code total, if not more!

I am just really hoping there is an alternative to the above. Now I know I can reduce a bit of the duplication by perhaps creating an automatically failing function that will always call the relevant `throwError` that I can defer to if the first guard doesn't hit, but even with that this still feels pretty gross.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the `Tok -> Maybe ()` and `Tok -> Maybe String` functions "for free" (via Template Haskell) by using prisms (e.g. from the [lens library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html)).

```
data Tok =
    IdLower String
  | IdUpper String
  | IdSymbol String
  | IdColon String
  | Equals
  | Newline

makePrisms ''Tok
```

Now you can say:

```
GHCi> preview _IdLower (IdLower "foo")
Just "foo"
GHCi> preview _IdLower (IdUpper "Foo")
Nothing
```

Then, as you suggest yourself, you can abstract from the prism in your token-specific function:

```
tok :: Prism' Tok a -> Parser a
tok p = get >>= \ s -> if
  | (_, t) :- xs <- s, Just n <- preview p t -> put xs *> pure n
  | (l, t) :- _ <- s -> throwError [(l, "Unexpected " <> description t)]
  | Nil l <- s -> throwError [(l, "Unexpected end of input")]
```

And then you can get the individual functions back by saying `tok _IdLower` or `tok _Equals`.

Comment: I like to avoid Template Haskell so I do still hope there is a TH-free solution. But with that said this still does seem like an incredibly effective solution, and I have a feeling that it might be hard to do this without TH, so thank you!

Comment: @semicolon In principle, you can also derive prisms using generic programming. Would that be more acceptable than using TH?

Comment: Is that what you are doing in your other answer?

Comment: @semicolon No, that's a totally different approach. Here, I was just talking about taking the prism-based approach, but rather than using TH to derive the prisms, using something like GHC generics. For example, the [stack-prism](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stack-prism) package, contains such code (but derives prisms of slightly different source and target types). This could probably be adapted to suit your needs.

Comment: Oh ok then yeah, generics definitely does seem like a more disciplined and rigorous method than TH, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a different approach that also requires a bit of boilerplate code, but no Template Haskell.

It's based on restructuring your `Tok` type so that you can use a form of equality test rather than matching, and can extract the payload of the token uniformly:

```
data Tok where
  Tok :: TokKind a -> a -> Tok
```

Every token has a token kind and a payload. The type of token kinds is a GADT
that determines the type of the payload:

```
data TokKind :: * -> * where
  IdLower  :: TokKind String
  IdUpper  :: TokKind String
  IdSymbol :: TokKind String
  IdColon  :: TokKind String
  Equal    :: TokKind ()
  Newline  :: TokKind ()
```

We now need a form of equality that implies that if two tokens have the same kind, their payload types must be compatible. This is what `testEquality` from `Data.Type.Equality` does (which unfortunately cannot currently be derived in any easy way, except by using TH again):

```
instance TestEquality TokKind where
  testEquality IdLower  IdLower  = Just Refl 
  testEquality IdUpper  IdUpper  = Just Refl 
  testEquality IdSymbol IdSymbol = Just Refl 
  testEquality IdColon  IdColon  = Just Refl 
  testEquality Equal    Equal    = Just Refl 
  testEquality Newline  Newline  = Just Refl 
  testEquality _        _        = Nothing
```

Then your parameterized token function becomes

```
tok :: TokKind a -> Parser a
tok tk' = get >>= \ s -> if
  | (_, Tok tk x) :- xs <- s, Just Refl <- testEquality tk tk' -> put xs *> pure x
  | (l, t) :- _ <- s -> throwError [(l, "Unexpected " <> description t)]
  | Nil l <- s -> throwError [(l, "Unexpected end of input")]
```